# Using Distance-field-fonts with scene2d

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, 2d, scene2d

I'm currently using Distance-field-fonts in my project as described here :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts

The way it functions is by creating a custom font made in hiero with the distance-field filter and applying a custom fragment shader to the batch while drawing fonts. After font drawing is done, the shader gets reset to null again.

This works without problems on normal fonts, but I can't find a way to use this technique alongside scene2d gui's. I have to set the shader of the batch before drawing a distance field font, and since I'm not able to directly access scene2d gui actor draw functions, I have no way to set the shader at the right moment (between texture and font draw calls of a button for example).

I'm currently using a workaround by extending the base gui Actor classes like Label and TextButton :

```
public class CustomLabel extends Label {

    public ShaderProgram fontShader;

    public CustomLabel(CharSequence text, Skin skin, ShaderProgram fontShader) {
        super(text, skin);
        this.fontShader = fontShader;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.setShader(fontShader);
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.setShader(null);
    }

}
```

But this isn't optimal since it's not possible for all standard scene2d gui classes like SelectBox & List.

The other problem is that every time you set a shader, the batch gets flushed, which could lead to 20-40 flushes per frame in a gui intensive game.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if theres no proper solution to this I would also consider switching to another font scaling solution (if theres any).

Comment: You're right. If you have a lot of text in separate widgets, you will have a lot of batch flushing. The only workaround I can think of is to create a custom Label that doesn't draw in it's draw method. Then once per frame you draw all the custom labels manually after drawing the stage. This depends on text not being overlapped by any other UI.